# Is it possible --from-file ConfigMap using kubernetes_config_map resource?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I want to deploy metallb using terraform. metallb configuration is as follows.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 172.16.99.1-172.16.99.255
```

Is it possible deploy such --from-file configuration using kubernetes_config_map resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [file() interpolation function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#file-path-) to read the file contents.  That might look like:

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "config" {
  metadata {
    namespace = "metallb_system"
    name = "config"
  }
  data {
    config = "${file(${path.module}/config.yml)}"
  }
}
```

Unlike `kubectl create configmap --from-file` you do have to specify the filename twice.

Comment: That’s exactly what I want to know. Thanks a lot.